# Update Query for Duplicate records

Tags: mysql

I have written the following query to identify the max value of the duplicates. How do I write and update query to update a status field for the max value of the duplicates?

```
Select MAX(pk_prod_id), create_date, ASI_ID, FK_SUBSIDIARY_ID
    FROM tbl_product
    where B_PROD_ACTIVE ='true'
    GROUP BY ASI_ID
    HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Could wrap this in an `UPDATE x WHERE id IN (....)` with the inner part of the `IN` clause being this `SELECT`.